# Iterate over dates, calculate averages for every 24-hour period

Tags: python, csv, date, average

I have a csv file with data every ~minute over 2 years, and am wanting to run code to calculate 24-hour averages. Ideally I'd like the code to iterate over the data, calculate averages and standard deviations, and R^2 between dataA and dataB, for every 24hr period and then output this new data into a new csv file (with datestamp and calculated data for each 24hr period).

[image: Example the csv data]

The data has an unusual timestamp which I think might be tripping me up slightly. I've been trying different For Loops to iterate over the data, but I'm not sure how to specify that I want the averages,etc for each 24hr period.

This is the code I have so far, but I'm not sure how to complete the For Loop to achieve what I'm wanting. If anyone can help that would be great!

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta, date

# read the file in csv
data = pd.read_csv("Jacaranda_data_HST.csv")

# Extract the data columns from the csv
data_date = data.iloc[:,1]
dataA  = data.iloc[:,2]
dataB  = data.iloc[:,3]

# set the start and end dates of the data
start_date = data_date.iloc[0]
end_date = data_date.iloc[-1:]

# for loop to run over every 24 hours of data
day_count = (end_date - start_date).days + 1
for single_date in [d for d in (start_date + timedelta(n) for n in 
range(day_count)) if d <= end_date]:
  print np.mean(dataA), np.mean(dataB), np.std(dataA), np.std(dataB)

# output new csv file - **unsure how to call the data** 
csvfile = "Jacaranda_new.csv"
outdf = pd.DataFrame()
#outdf['dataA_mean'] = ??
#outdf['dataB_mean'] = ??
#outdf['dataA_stdev'] = ??
#outdf['dataB_stdev'] = ??
outdf.to_csv(csvfile, index=False)
```

Comment: I don't understand: this "24h period" refers to grouping by calender day? Do you want to calculate the mean of all datapoint from the 2018-05-26, then the mean from the 27th (which there seem to be no data points for that date in your example data, so the mean would be 0), then for the next day, and so on?

Comment: Yes, grouping by calendar day is what I'm aiming for. Some of the days won't have any data, but most have thousands of rows in the csv file.

Comment: You have datetimes in UTC and HST (UTC-10). What is your definition of a day, from 00:00 UTC or from 00:00 HST, and can Daylight Saving Time (HDT) be involved?

Comment: The data comes from Hawaii, so the definition of the day is from 00:00 Hawaii Standard Time (HST). Daylight Saving Time doesn't need to be involved, think it would make it more complicated than it needs to be! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplified aproach could be to group by calendar day in a `dict`. I don't have much experience with `pandas` time management in DataFrames, so this could be an alternative.

You could create a `dict` where the keys are the dates of the data (without the time part), so you can later calculate the mean of all the data points that are under each key.

```
data_date = data.iloc[:,1]
data_a  = data.iloc[:,2]
data_b  = data.iloc[:,3]

import collections
dd_a = collections.defaultdict(list)
dd_b = collections.defaultdict(list)

for date_str, data_point_a, data_point_b in zip(data_date, data_a, data_b):
    # we split the string by the first space, so we get only the date part
    date_part, _ = date_str.split(' ', maxsplit=1)

    dd_a[date_part].append(data_point_a)
    dd_b[date_part].append(data_point_b)
```

Now you can calculate the averages:

```
for date, v_list in dd_a.items():
    if len(v_list) > 0:
        print(date, 'mean:', sum(v_list) / len(v_list))
for date, v_list in dd_b.items():
    if len(v_list) > 0:
        print(date, 'mean:', sum(v_list) / len(v_list))
```

Comment: Thanks Ralf, that seems like a very neat way around the problem! Unfortunately it comes up with this TypeError 

"date_part, _ = date_str.split(' ', maxsplit=1)
TypeError: split() takes no keyword arguments" - any ideas?

Comment: Ah! Python 2 vs Python 3 error, sorted it now :) Thanks so much!